# Different Like button´s in same domain?

Tags: facebook

I´ve an album on my web where user´s can "Like" every pic. I´m usin the like button but it count´s for all images. This images are in different pages like:

http://www.comeok.es/receta130

http://www.comeok.es/receta131

Each like is counting for the whole page www.comeok.es

The data-href attribute is linking the current page, i also change og:url content attr with current URL...

Any idea?, thnks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a debug tool provided by Facebook called the [Object Debugger](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) (it used to be called fblint).  In your open graph code you have the page URL defined as:

```
http://www.comeok.es/receta130/
```

Which if you pass to the object debugger ([direct link](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http://www.comeok.es/receta130/)). Returns some errors (possibly related to that trailing slash.

Some of the errors include:

```
Too Many Redirects: URL redirected too many times. Please reduce the number of redirects.

Admins And App ID Missing:  fb:admins and fb:app_id tags are missing. These tags are necessary for Facebook to render a News Feed story that generates a high click-through rate
```